# I am having a z-index dropdown issue

Tags: html, css, navigation, z-index

I am trying to put the drop down bar behind the main nav bar and this is working with z-index however once you take your cursor off the main nav and move towards the drop down the drop down disappears not allowing you to click the links. Any help would be awesome!

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/PwgNT/)

HTML

```
<nav class="top-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Headshots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Performances</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Fantasticks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Little Women</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tough Jet Girl</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!--- End top-nav -->
```

CSS

```
.top-nav ul ul {
background: #E08399;
background: linear-gradient(top, #E08399 0%, #D66082 40%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E08399 0%, #D66082 40%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E08399 0%,#D66082 40%); 
border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; 
padding-left: 0px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #9C8066;
z-index: -1;
```

Comment: jsfiddle?  probably a small pixel diff between pos of child element and menu which means its technically not being hovered anymore at a guess.

Comment: it would be nice if you can describe lite better what you are trying to archive and which browser do you have problem with.

Comment: This is in chrome and I want the drop down menu to fall behind the navigation bar which I have achieved however when you pull your mouse towards the drop down the drop down disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdown menu getting disappear because it is not having any connection with your parent element. So you need to assign position:relative to your parent element. It means your child element absolute position will calculate inside the parent element and it will visible under this parent.

**CSS:**

```
 .top-nav ul li:hover ul {
  background: #E08399;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #E08399 0%, #D66082 40%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E08399 0%, #D66082 40%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E08399 0%,#D66082 40%); 
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px; 
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #9C8066;
  z-index: 5;
  display:block;
  list-style-type:none;
  }
  .top-nav ul li ul{display:none}
  .top-nav ul li{position:relative;}
```

[**Have a Fiddle Demo!**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/PwgNT/3/)